# Java Soap and JPA

Tags: java, jpa, soap

i'm trying to get my SOAP working with JPA. But I've found a really weird issue.

The following occurs when I unit test this registerUser method:

```
String email = "xx2@nl";
    String omsch = "omsch";

    User seller1 = registrationMgr.registerUser(email);
    Category cat = new Category();
```

In the database the user is persisted.

When I, however use this same code from my SOAP webclient. It does not register the user in the database.

How I get the RegistrationManager in client:

`RegistrationService rservice = new RegistrationService();
        registrationMgr = rservice.getRegistrationPort();`

The register user method does the following (so this is on server side):

```
    user = new User(email);
    userDAO.create(user);
    return user;
```

And in the userDAO the create function:

```
public void create(User user) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(user);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

So a summary;
When I use the same piece of code from the unit test of the server it works, but from the SOAP client it does not.

Any help is appreciated! 
Let me know if you need any more code or information!

Comment: have you debugged your code?

Comment: Yes I have, The unit test returns a user in both cases. The error message from JPA is: During synchronisation a new object was found which is not marked as persist. I think this is because the unit test in SOAP client does not save the User in the database, therfore another unit test cannot find this user

Comment: well, what does your unit test different from your soap? and a unit test is not debugging. also your user should have a unique identifier

Comment: I know unit test is different from debugging :). The only difference is that it does not access the JPARegistrationManager (with the register user in it) directly from local packages, but trough SOAP.